# Unable to run javascript code in .jade file

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am working on node js project and using .jade template, as per requirement I want to run js code but unable to write it.

Code in .jade file

```
    extends layout
    
    block content
      if authorised
        p Welcome #{fname} | 
          a(href="/exit") Log Out
        if typeof users != 'undefined'
        p User list
        ul
          each user in users
            li= user.user_fname
      else
        p Don't have an account yet? 
          a(href='/register') Register
        p Already have an account? 
          a(href='/login') Login
    script.
   JSON.stringify(data),// passing data from routes
    alert('some text');
```

Comment: When viewing `view source` in the browser, does the outputted code include a `script` tag with the correct script inside?

Comment: @Tyler2P no  actually i am new to node  and all, so just following demo project

Comment: Indentation matters in Pug. Your `script.` tag must be indented one level greater than your `block content` declaration, and the javascript must be indented one level greater than the `script.` tag.

Comment: @Sean can u please show this, by updating answer, I need example  for this, simply description can't help me.